# above widgets are done by pageview builder and below is listview builder

Tags: flutter, uipageviewcontroller, flutter-pageview, flutter-slider, flutter-scrollbar

I want to make it responsive like if I move the slider then correspondent list which is below should be highlighted and should move according to the slider.

I have tried PageView controller to pass in ListView controller but it never worked.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand the problem please add images or code to make your question clear @Ajith S

Comment: Show us your failed attempt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.